# javascript how to add a variable to a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using javascript and jquery, I have a string like

```
  var apiUrlAnswer = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/answers/{ids}?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow';
```

I need replace the `{ids}` with a variable.

In C# is possible to use a method called

```
String.Format(https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/answers/{0}?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow, myVariable);
```

I would like to know if exist something similar in Javascript so I can avoid simple string concatenation.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well here's a String.format (like c#); I've extended javascripts `String` object to include a format method like this:

```
String.format = function(stringToFormat, argsForFormat) {

    for (var i = 0; i < argsForFormat.length; i++) {
        var regex = new RegExp('\{(' + i + ')}', 'g');
        stringToFormat = stringToFormat.replace(regex, argsForFormat[i]);
    }

    return stringToFormat;    
};
```

You can call it like this

```
var args = [1, 'activity', 'stackoverflow', 'desc']   
var apiUrlAnswer = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/answers/{0}?order={3}&sort={1}&site={2}';
var apiUrlAnswer = String.format(apiUrlAnswer, args);
```

Or an inline version would look like this

```
var apiUrlAnswer = String.format('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/answers/{0}?order={3}&sort={1}&site={2}', [1, 'activity', 'stackoverflow', 'desc']);
```

and another example

```
String.format("http://{0}.{1}.com", ['www', 'stackoverflow']);
```

Comment: +1. Nice. Or even better, `replace(new RegExp('{'+i+'}', 'g'), ...` so that it can replace multiple instances of `{0}`.

Comment: @nnnnnn amended as suggested but could only get it to work with a more complex pattern `'\{(' + i + ')}'`

Answer (score 5):

Use the String [`.replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
var apiUrlAnswer = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/answers/{ids}?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow';

apiUrlAnswer = apiUrlAnswer.replace("{ids}", yourVariable);

// OR, if there might be more than one instance of '{ids}' use a regex:
apiUrlAnswer = apiUrlAnswer.replace(/\{ids\}/g, yourVariable);
```

Comment: Thanks nnnnnn.. do you know alternative day to do it?

Comment: There are any number of ways to do it using whatever combination of JavaScript's [`String` manipulation methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/#Methods_unrelated_to_HTML) takes your fancy, but `.replace()` is an easy way to do it with one statement...

Comment: P.S. There are some libraries that implement a `String.format()` type function, e.g., [sprintf() for JavaScript](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf). If you Google "JavaScript String.format" you'll get a bunch of options.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this frequently,  a more robust alternative to using a regex is to use a client side templating engine like [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/). I have used this successfully and it's quick and lightweight.

```
var view = {
  ids: "Andrew"
};

var output = Mustache.render("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/answers/{{ids}}?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow", view);
```

This has the advantage of separating your data and presentation nicely.

Answer (score 0):

How about just using replace:

```
apiUrlAnswer = apiUrlAnswer.replace('{ids}', 'test');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var id = 'your_id';
var apiUrlAnswer = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/answers/'+id+'?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow';
```